# Как добавить скролл к JTextArea на JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

Добрый вечер.

Возникла проблема при добавлении JScrollPane на JTextArea, который располагается на панели. Скролл в данном случае не появляется. Как нужно поступить? Если же JTextArea располагается просто на JFrame, то все работает как надо.

```
public exampleTextAreaWithScroll() {
        JPanel j = new JPanel();
        jta = new JTextArea(10, 20);
        jsp = new JScrollPane(jta,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        j.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        j.add(jta);
        j.add(jsp);
        add(j);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: Нет, не дубликат. Вы мой пост читали?

Comment: вы добавляете textarea и scrollpane, а надо добавлять только scrollpane (убрать строку `j.add(jta);`). В content pane на jframe используется `BorderLayout`, `add` которого помещает компонент в `BorderLayout.CENTER` "затирая" предыдущий, поэтому все работает.

Comment: Да уж, как-то не особо это логично. Но спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Я немного поменял твой код, всё работает

```
public void exampleTextAreaWithScroll() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 20);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel.add(scroll);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Полагаю, проблема была в том, что ты добавил текстовую область и на панель, и на скролл-панель - один `add` лишний